# javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [{pz:instanceof(object,'com.project.domain.MyClass')}]

Tags: jsf, facelets, el, tomcat7

Currenty I have a web project with JSF 1.2 and Facelets running in tomcat 6.0.18.0. I decided to upgrade the servlet container, thus i deployed in tomcat 7 and all seemed ok until we hit one view using my custome facelet functions.

`javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [{pz:instanceof(object,'com.project.domain.MyClass')}]`

```
Caused by: org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " ":" ": "" at line 1, column 5. Was expecting one of:
"}" ...
"." ...
"[" ...
```

This error occurs when parsing the following code:

```
<ui:repeat var="object" value="#{objects}">
<ui:fragment rendered="#{pz:instanceof(object,'com.project.domain.MyClass')}">
...
```

If i understand correctly it throws an error because of the colon in the expression . I have tracked it down to the jasper-el that come with in the tomcat/lib directory, and if I replace jasper.jar and jasper-el.jar with the ones from tomcat 6.0.18 everythign works well.

Has anyone else had this problem before upgrading their tomcat? And How did they resolve it?
Could I deploy in production tomcat 7 with these jasper jar from tomcat 6, or could this cause further problems.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is actually a misleading exception. It has a different underlying cause. The function name `instanceof` is invalid.

The [EL 2.2 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) says the following:

> ## 1.14 Reserved Words
>
> The following words are reserved for the language and must not be used as
>   identifiers.
>
> ```
>     and   eq     gt     true   instanceof
>     or    ne     le     false  empty
>     not   lt     ge     null   div        mod
> ```
>
> Note that many of these words are not in the language now, but they may be in the
>   future, so developers must avoid using these words.

and

> ## 1.19 Collected Syntax
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Identifier ::= Java language identifier
> ```
>
> ...

Where the Java language identifier stands for keywords like `instanceof`, `if`, `while`, `class`, `return`, `static`, `new`, etc. They may not be used as variable/function names in EL. In case you have properties with those names, use the brace notation instead like so `#{bean['class'].simpleName}` instead of `#{bean.class.simpleName}`.

This was been fixed in Tomcat 7.0.4 or somewhere near before this version as indicated by [issue 50147](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50147) wherein someone else pointed out the same problem as you have. So, to solve your problem, you have to rename your EL function name to for example `isInstanceOf` or something.

Comment: That will teach me not to name functions with reserved words, petty the error message did not list those aswell it could have saved me a lot of headache. Thanks again BalusC.

Answer (score 8):

Add this line in catalina.properties ([tomcat folder]/conf), and it should fix the issue.

```
org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
```

However, you should not use the reserved words.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, i did this too. In fact if I remeber correctly, this was one of the first changes I made, however if you still have a function that resembles a reserved word, such as "instanceof' it will still throw an error.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try changing the syntax.  I had the same exact problem with code that I was maintaining when we were moving from Tomcat 6 to 7.  I had to change `myobject.class.name` to `myobject['class'].name`.  After I made this change my code worked perfectly again.

Comment: Pure gold, that response.  Thank you!  It was also applicable moving from Jetty 7 to Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 2):

Great hint, indeed! I had to change in my jspx ${instance.class.simpleName == ...} with ${instance['class'].simpleName eq ...}.

I was moving from vFabric on tomcat 6 to vFabric on tomcat 7