# Failed to parse the expression [#{myCartController.cartView == 'RETAIL_PRICE_GROSS' and fn:endsWith(myCartController.class.name,'.CartController')}]

Tags: jsf, tomcat, el

I have a problem with this line in my code:

```
rendered="#{myCartController.cartView == 'RETAIL_PRICE_GROSS' and fn:endsWith(myCartController.class.name,'.CartController')}"
```

It works without problems on Tomcat 6, but on Tomcat 7, it throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [#{myCartController.cartView == 'RETAIL_PRICE_GROSS' and fn:endsWith(myCartController.class.name,'.CartController')}]
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:146)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:172)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:67)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttribute.getValueExpression(TagAttribute.java:256)
    ... 93 more
```

Did something change in the EL syntax between Tomcat 6 and 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is here:

```
fn:endsWith(myCartController.class.name,'.CartController')
```

Since Tomcat 7.0.4, Java language identifiers like `new`, `instanceof`, `class`, `public`, etc are not allowed anymore as EL variable/function names. This is a consequence of bugfix on chapter 1.19 of EL 2.2 specification.

You need to specify them as plain strings in brace notation:

```
fn:endsWith(myCartController['class'].name,'.CartController')
```

#### See also:

- [javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [{pz:instanceof(object,'com.project.domain.MyClass')}]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866769/javax-el-elexception-failed-to-parse-the-expression-pzinstanceofobject-com/7867250#7867250)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the particular expression can be improved as follows by using `Class#getSimpleName()` instead of `Class#getName()`:

```
myCartController['class'].simpleName == 'CartController'
```